# format array to output in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var toFormat = [[1, "one", "unu"], [2, "two", "du"], [3, "three", "tri"], [4, "four", "kvar"]];
```

I need to output array `toFormat` so it should look like this:

```
1 (one)
2 (two)
3 (three)
4 (four)
```

(The third element of every sub-array is not used)
How to do that?

EDIT: The loop is here

```
var res = []; 
for(var i=0;i<toFormat.length;i++){
    res.push(toFormat[i][1]+" ("+toFormat[i][2]+")");
}
console.log(res.join("\n"))
```

Comment: tried the loop but i dont really think it will work

Comment: Post your loop.

Comment: var res = []; for(var i=0;i<toFormat.length;i++){res.push(toFormat[i][1]+" ("+toFormat[i][2]+")");}console.log(res.join("\n"));

Comment: And the body of your for loop?, also edit your question with this not in a comment...

Comment: You are using 1 and 2 as the indexes and not 0 and 1. https://jsfiddle.net/5aqzkeox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of ways this can be done. I'd personally recommend using a `for...of` loop, like this

```js
// defining the array to loop over
const toFormat = [
  [1, 'one', 'unu'],
  [2, 'two', 'du'],
  [3, 'three', 'tri'],
  [4, 'four', 'kvar']
];

for (let i of toFormat) {
  console.log(i[0] + " (" + i[1] + ")");
}
```

Of course, if you want this as a string instead of being printed you can do this instead

```js
// defining the array to loop over
const toFormat = [
  [1, 'one', 'unu'],
  [2, 'two', 'du'],
  [3, 'three', 'tri'],
  [4, 'four', 'kvar']
];

let formatted = "";
for (let i of toFormat) {
  formatted += (i[0] + " (" + i[1] + ")\n");
}
console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: From MDN: *It is strongly recommended that assignment operators (+, +=) are used instead of the concat() method.*

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for the advice! I did not know. I'll fix my answer to use `+` instead of `concat`.

Answer (score 5):

```js
const toFormat = [
   [1, "one",   "unu"], 
   [2, "two",   "du"], 
   [3, "three", "tri"], 
   [4, "four",  "kvar"]];

const result = toFormat.map(([val, string]) => `${val} (${string})`).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In this one liner solution there is quite good use of es6 features :)

Comment: Nice use of interpolation!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have omitted the closing quote of the last index in the last array.

But, barring that, the `[Array.prototype.forEach()]` method can [do the trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var toFormat = [[1, "one", "unu"], [2, "two", "du"], [3, "three", "tri"], [4, "four", "kvar"]];
  
toFormat.forEach(function(item, index, arry){
    console.log(item[0] + " (" + item[1] + ")");
});
```